P90 Magazine Design Fail
I need help designing a Lego magazine for my Lego p90 gun project. If you don’t know, a p90 magazine twists the bullet's orientation in a spiral. I need a way to make that in Lego pieces. Is there any way to make this? I was going for a mechanism like Snyzer Tech’s P90:


What scale are you working with? Can you share the current progress of the design, so that the suggested ideas have something to build upon, instead of hanging in the void?

That’s the problem, I haven’t made any progress. I have made the magazine itself, just not the spiral.

How is the attached example inadequate? In what aspects do you want to change it? (Or in other words: why don't just copy it?)

Because he charges money for the instructions, and in pounds, not US dollars.

I mean why not reverse engineer the same solution visible on the photo and in the video? As far as I see it is just a simple arrangement of common beams to form appropriately angled slopes. Take a few more screenshots where the video shows the assembly from slightly different angles and with a bit of trial-and-error you should have the exact copy soon.

I have been trying for days to do that, but it is to complicated to reverse engineer, especially with the limited angles he showed us.

If I were to start this project, I'd consider using the spiral staircase pieces to build a curved staircase and see if it can work sufficiently with the rest of the mechanisms and scales.

Another option would be to use flexible parts, such as pneumatic hoses attached via clips to constrain them to a spiral shape, but due to their inherent flexibility they would not be able to exert too much force.

That is too big, and I don’t have pneumatic tubes. I was thinking it could be 4x3x6 studs in size

Ah, it seems I have misunderstood the question and thought you were requesting help with a magazine that stores the cartridges in a spiral, as in a Calico Liberty. But thanks to your edit it is now clearer what you had in mind.
